# how to test Add when saving Associates Cakephp

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, testing, save, cakephp-2.0

how to test such a method:

```
public function add() {
if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Contest->create();

        if ($this->Contest->saveAll($this->request->data)) {


            $contestStage['name'] = 'First - ' . $this->request->data['Contest']['name'];
            $contestStage['contest_id'] = $this->Contest->id;

            if ($this->Contest->ContestStage->save($contestStage)) {
                $this->setMessage(__ADD_OK, 'Konkurs');
                $this->redirect(array(
                    'action' => 'view',
                    $this->Contest->id
                ));
            } else {
                $this->setMessage(__ADD_ERROR, 'Konkurs');
            }
        } else {
            $this->setMessage(__ADD_ERROR, 'Konkurs');
        }
    }
}
```

my test method:

```
public function testAdd() {
        $this->generateWithAuth(self::ADMIN); // genereting controller here
        $url = $this->getUrl('add');
        $options2 = array(
            'method' => 'post',
            'data' => array(
                'Contest' => array(
                    'id' => 3,
                    'owner_id' => 1,
                    'name' => 'Testing',
                    'created' => '2012-11-16 12:02:33.946',
                ),
            ),
            );
        $this->testAction($url, $options2); 
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('Location', $this->headers, 'No redirection');
        $this->assertEquals($this->Contest->hasAny(array('Contest.name' => 'Testing')), true);    
        $messages = Set::extract('{flash}.message', CakeSession::read('Message'));
    }
```

what i receive is

```
PDOEXCEPTION
SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 BŁĄD: double key value violates a constraint
```

uniqueness "contest_stages_pkey" DETAIL: Key (id)=(1) alredy exists.

Because it's true i have a contestStage with id=1
why its not using next one ;<

Answer (score 0):

Its kinda strange that Cakephp does not document how to test that well.

The problem is that your inserting the Contest id twice. You should make sure that the db that your using has a test prefix (or whatever you like) and clear the test tables.

As an alternative, you could use fixtures instead. The data produces a much better test case as it pre populates the data for you so that you know whats in the db at any time. Still make sure to use a prefix, I made the mistake once of not doing that and it blew away my entire db every time

Good luck